# Checking username availability by using a request sent to the API (Retrofit)

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

I'm trying to create a simple application that handles the login and registration process.
I have a problem with validating my sign up form. I want to check if entered username is available. I have an endpoint created for this purpose which returns JSON with a single value {"bool" : "true"} or {"bool" : "false"}.

I validate provided data with the following function:

```
private boolean validateUsername(){
    String val = usernameInput.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

    checkIfUsernameIsAvailable(val);

    if(val.isEmpty()){
        usernameInput.setError("Field can not be empty");
        return false;
    } else if(val.length() > 20) {
        usernameInput.setError("Username is too large");
        return false;
    } else if(isUsernameInUse) {
        usernameInput.setError("Username is already in use");
        return false;
    } else {
        usernameInput.setError(null);
        usernameInput.setErrorEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except checking user availability. Namely: the thread that sends the request to the API sometimes fails to execute it before executing the IF.

This is how the request is sent:

```
private void checkIfUsernameIsAvailable(String username){
    ExistsUsernameDTO existsUsernameDTO = new ExistsUsernameDTO(username);
    Call<BooleanDTO> call = userService.existsByUsername(existsUsernameDTO);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<BooleanDTO>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<BooleanDTO> call, Response<BooleanDTO> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                isUsernameInUse = response.body().getBool();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "username_check_failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<BooleanDTO> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

This is a function started when a button REGISTER is clicked:

```
public void callNextRegisterScreen(View view) {

    if (!validateUsername()){
        return;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterUserDetailsActivity.class);

    Pair[] pairs = new Pair[4];
    pairs[0] = new Pair<View, String>(backBtn, "transition_back_arrow_btn");
    pairs[1] = new Pair<View, String>(titleText, "transition_title_text");
    pairs[2] = new Pair<View, String>(nextBtn, "transition_next_btn");
    pairs[3] = new Pair<View, String>(loginBtn, "transition_login_btn");

    ActivityOptions activityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(RegisterActivity.this, pairs);
    startActivity(intent, activityOptions.toBundle());
}
```

How to make the verification wait for the query to be executed or how to perform this validation in a better way?

Comment: Though I am not familiar with android development from logical point of view I would say you should send this check only after you have done with the checks for emptiness and length. That means if these 2 checks fail there is no need to send the call in the first place anyway.

Comment: Yes, I wanted the checking function to be executed after emptiness and length validation but I don't know how to make checkIfUsernameIsAvailable function to return boolean value (It's difficult because it uses an inner class). Also, in another forum thread, people wrote that an async function should return void, not boolean

Comment: I think callNextRegisterScreen should be triggered in success case of checkIfUsernameIsAvailable method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to navigate to the next screen when your "Username Available" network request returns success, for example you can refactor your code to be as follows:

```
public void callNextRegisterScreen() {
    validateUsername()
}

private void validateUsername(){
    String val = usernameInput.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

    if(val.isEmpty()){
        usernameInput.setError("Field can not be empty");
        return;
    } else if(val.length() > 20) {
        usernameInput.setError("Username is too large");
        return;
    } else if(isUsernameInUse) {
        usernameInput.setError("Username is already in use");
        return;
    }

    checkIfUsernameIsAvailable(val);
}

private void checkIfUsernameIsAvailable(String username){
    ExistsUsernameDTO existsUsernameDTO = new ExistsUsernameDTO(username);
    Call<BooleanDTO> call = userService.existsByUsername(existsUsernameDTO);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<BooleanDTO>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<BooleanDTO> call, Response<BooleanDTO> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                isUsernameInUse = response.body().getBool();
                if(isUsernameInUse)
                  Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "username in use",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                  navigateNextRegisterScreen()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "username_check_failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<BooleanDTO> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}


public void navigateNextRegisterScreen(){

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterUserDetailsActivity.class);

    Pair[] pairs = new Pair[4];
    pairs[0] = new Pair<View, String>(backBtn, "transition_back_arrow_btn");
    pairs[1] = new Pair<View, String>(titleText, "transition_title_text");
    pairs[2] = new Pair<View, String>(nextBtn, "transition_next_btn");
    pairs[3] = new Pair<View, String>(loginBtn, "transition_login_btn");

    ActivityOptions activityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(RegisterActivity.this, pairs);
    startActivity(intent, activityOptions.toBundle());
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Your solution helped a lot ;)

Comment: Your most welcome, in case the answer was helpful in you case, please make as accepted or upvote, so others can recognize the problem and the solution